# How to correctly install a file-based dependency in a Vite project

Tags: file, dependencies, jsx, vite

In a CRA project, I use `npm install file:../foo` to install a dependency called `foo`.

The dependency `foo` is located one level up in the directory tree relative to the CRA project's root.

In the JSX files in the CRA-based project, I can use either `import foo/dist/foo.js` or `import { ... } from 'foo'` to bring in code. This works fine.

In a stock Vite project created with `npm create vite@latest`, I tried the same `npm install file:../foo` command to install the dependency.

When loading my Vite project in development mode (`npm run dev`), I get the following error, if I use `import foo/dist/foo.js`:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "foo/dist/foo.js" from "src/App.jsx". Does the file exist?
```

If I instead use `import { Bar } from 'foo'`, I get a different error:

```
The requested module '/@fs/Users/areynolds/Developer/Github/foo/dist/foo.js' does not provide an export named 'Bar' (at App.jsx:11:3)
```

I'm not sure where `/@fs` is coming from, but the rest of the path is correct: The file `foo/dist/foo.js` (or `/Users/areynolds/Developer/Github/foo/dist/foo.js`) does indeed exist, and this import works correctly in the CRA-based project that is at the same level in the directory tree as the Vite project.

If I look at `node_modules`, the symlink that should be there is incorrect:

```
$ ls -al node_modules/foo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 areynolds  staff  13 Aug 27 13:36 node_modules/foo -> ../../foo
```

This should instead look like:

```
node_modules/foo -> ../foo
```

Even if I manually fix the symlink, I get the same import errors.

What configuration step is required in Vite's `package.json` (or other configuration files) to make `file:...` based dependencies work correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Why you're adding `file:` to npm install command? wouldn't be better if you used an absolute path like `npm install ../foo` it seems to me  `/@fs/` is caused by this `file:` .. Also make sure you're exporting from the foo.js and you ran `npm init` in the foo folder

Answer (score 1):

To add a local file based dependency to a vite project .. we will use foo to keep the example simple

1. First in the `foo` folder which is one level up make sure to run

```bash
npm init -y
```

2. In any file in the foo folder make sure you export what you need default export or named export .. for instance here what a `foo.js` could look like

```js
const foo = 'foo from foo folder'
const anotherFoo = 'another foo'
const bar = 'Bar'

export {anotherFoo, bar}
export default foo
```

3. In the vite project run :

```
npm install ../foo
```

In you App.jsx import and use the code

```js
import foo, {anotherFoo, bar} from 'foo'
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using "resolutions" in your package.json in your Vite project?

Sometimes in Vite, the behavior for local dependency imports behaves differently than CRA due to the way vite resolves paths.

Try setting something like this:

```
"resolutions": {
  "foo": "file:../foo"
}
```

Test this in your Vite project's package.json.